# Treat Entry As Primary Key Print Once, Print Associated Entry Array, As CSV, Drop Empties

Tags: jq

I have records like these with sometimes duplicate `srcPath` entries, though with different `references`.

For example `/content/dam/foo/about-bar/photos/rayDavis.PNG` appears 3 times in one record, with different `references`.

I'd like to get the unique `srcPath` printed once, and the associated `references`.

I also have empty records,

```
{
  "pages": []
}
```

I don't want to see those.

I'd really like a csv with:

`srcPath`, perhaps a different field like `published`, and first `reference`, second `reference`, third `reference`, etc. -- associated `references` array as consecutive comma separated values on the same line, like:

```
"/content/dam/foo/about-bar/pdf/theplan.pdf", true, "/content/foo/en/about-bar/the-plan-and-vision/jcr:content/content2/image/link", "/content/foo/en/about-bar/the-plan-and-vision/jcr:content/content2/textboximg/boxFtr", "/content/foo/en/about-bar/the-plan-and-vision/jcr:content/content1/textboximg/text"

"/content/dam/foo/about-bar/photos/rayDavis.PNG", true, "/content/foo/en/about-bar/jcr:content/content1B/promos_1/image/fileReference", "/content/foo/en/about-bar/monkey-development/tales-of-giving/ray-moose-davis/jcr:content/content1/textboximg/fileReference", "/content/foo/en/about-bar/monkey-development/tales-of-giving/jcr:content/content1/textboximg_2/fileReference"

"/content/dam/foo/about-bar/pdf/foo_19thNewsletter.pdf", true, "/content/foo/en/gremlins/stay-tuned/jcr:content/content3/textboximg/text"

"/content/dam/foo/about-bar/pdf/barNews_fall1617.pdf", true, "/content/foo/en/gremlins/jcr:content/content2C/textboximg_114671747/text", "/content/dam/foo/about-bar/pdf/barNews_fall1617.pdf", "/content/foo/en/gremlins/stay-tuned/jcr:content/content3/textboximg_0/text"
```

In other words, unique `srcPath` entries with associated `references`.

I imagine if I wanted `path` too, I wouldn't be able to have unique `srcPath` lines in the csv?

DATA:

```
{
  "pages": [
    {
      "srcPath": "/content/dam/foo/about-bar/pdf/theplan.pdf",
      "srcTitle": "theplan.pdf",
      "path": "/content/foo/en/about-bar/the-plan-and-vision",
      "title": "the Plan and Vision",
      "references": [
        "/content/foo/en/about-bar/the-plan-and-vision/jcr:content/content2/image/link",
        "/content/foo/en/about-bar/the-plan-and-vision/jcr:content/content2/textboximg/boxFtr",
        "/content/foo/en/about-bar/the-plan-and-vision/jcr:content/content1/textboximg/text"
      ],
      "published": false,
      "isPage": "true"
    }
  ]
}






{
  "pages": []
}



{
  "pages": []
}


{
  "pages": [
    {
      "srcPath": "/content/dam/foo/about-bar/photos/rayDavis.PNG",
      "srcTitle": "rayDavis.PNG",
      "path": "/content/foo/en/about-bar",
      "title": "About bar",
      "references": [
        "/content/foo/en/about-bar/jcr:content/content1B/promos_1/image/fileReference"
      ],
      "published": true,
      "isPage": "true"
    },
    {
      "srcPath": "/content/dam/foo/about-bar/photos/rayDavis.PNG",
      "srcTitle": "rayDavis.PNG",
      "path": "/content/foo/en/about-bar/monkey-development/tales-of-giving/ray-moose-davis",
      "title": "ray moose Davis",
      "references": [
        "/content/foo/en/about-bar/monkey-development/tales-of-giving/ray-moose-davis/jcr:content/content1/textboximg/fileReference"
      ],
      "published": true,
      "isPage": "true"
    },
    {
      "srcPath": "/content/dam/foo/about-bar/photos/rayDavis.PNG",
      "srcTitle": "rayDavis.PNG",
      "path": "/content/foo/en/about-bar/monkey-development/tales-of-giving",
      "title": "tales of Giving",
      "references": [
        "/content/foo/en/about-bar/monkey-development/tales-of-giving/jcr:content/content1/textboximg_2/fileReference"
      ],
      "published": true,
      "isPage": "true"
    }
  ]
}









{
  "pages": [
    {
      "srcPath": "/content/dam/foo/about-bar/pdf/foo_19thNewsletter.pdf",
      "srcTitle": "foo_19thNewsletter.pdf",
      "path": "/content/foo/en/gremlins/stay-tuned",
      "title": "Stay tuned",
      "references": [
        "/content/foo/en/gremlins/stay-tuned/jcr:content/content3/textboximg/text"
      ],
      "published": true,
      "isPage": "true"
    }
  ]
}









{
  "pages": [
    {
      "srcPath": "/content/dam/foo/about-bar/pdf/barNews_fall1617.pdf",
      "srcTitle": "barNews_fall1617.pdf",
      "path": "/content/foo/en/gremlins",
      "title": "gremlins",
      "references": [
        "/content/foo/en/gremlins/jcr:content/content2C/textboximg_114671747/text"
      ],
      "published": true,
      "isPage": "true"
    },
    {
      "srcPath": "/content/dam/foo/about-bar/pdf/barNews_fall1617.pdf",
      "srcTitle": "barNews_fall1617.pdf",
      "path": "/content/foo/en/gremlins/stay-tuned",
      "title": "Stay tuned",
      "references": [
        "/content/foo/en/gremlins/stay-tuned/jcr:content/content3/textboximg_0/text"
      ],
      "published": true,
      "isPage": "true"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
jq --raw-output '.pages | group_by(.srcPath)[] | [.[0].srcPath, .[0].published, .[].references[]] | @csv'
```

We group the pages by srcPath and map each group into an array that contains the srcPath and published of the first element of the group as well as the references of each element of the group. Each of these arrays will be a row in the CSV result.

[Try it here !](https://jqplay.org/s/vcuiS2Hjrn)

Comment: Holy smokes, that seems to work!! Thank you Aaron :)